# How to get all rows as a vector with tiberius futures?

Tags: sql-server, rust, rust-tokio

I need to collect all the rows of a table using [tiberius](https://github.com/steffengy/tiberius) and output them. My simple code is:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tiberius;

use futures::Future;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use tiberius::SqlConnection;
use tiberius::stmt::ResultStreamExt;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();

    let future = SqlConnection::connect(core.handle(), "server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;username=SA;password=qweasdZXC123!!;")
        .and_then(|conn| {
            let mut v: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

            conn.simple_query("SELECT id, name FROM test").for_each_row(|row| {

                let id: i32 = row.get(0);
                let name: &str = row.get(1);

                v.push(format!("{} - {}", id, name));

                Ok(())
            });

            println!("{:?}", v);

            Ok(())
        });

    core.run(future).unwrap();
}
```

This code prints an empty vector, but I need full vector of strings. I have read some articles about futures, but as as newbie to Rust, they look too complicated for me.

Comment: What's not working exactly? Is there an error?

Comment: It compiles but hangs on request. I think problem in wait() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, you had

```
conn.simple_query("SELECT id, name FROM users").for_each_row(|row| {
    // ...
}).wait().unwrap();
```

And you said "It compiles but hangs on request. I think problem in `wait()` call.".

If you read the documentation for [`Future::wait`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.wait), you'll see this warning, emphasis mine:

> Note: This method is not appropriate to call on event loops or similar I/O situations because it will prevent the event loop from making progress (**this blocks the thread**). This method should only be called when it's guaranteed that the blocking work associated with this future will be completed by another thread.

In your updated code, you have

```
conn.simple_query("SELECT id, name FROM test").for_each_row(|row| {
    // ...
});
```

This constructs a future but then drops it immediately, thus nothing ever happens to the outer vector. All of the futures in the futures crate have a warning attached to them for exactly this reason:

> warning: unused `futures::FutureResult` which must be used: futures do nothing unless polled

I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/steffengy/tiberius/issues/34) so that the library adds this.

---

Here's a **completely untested** piece of code. I don't have a SQL Server instance around to actually test it, but it does compile and has the right shape.

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate futures_state_stream;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tiberius;

use futures::{Future, Stream};
use futures_state_stream::StateStream;
use tiberius::SqlConnection;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();

    let connection_string = "server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;username=SA;password=qweasdZXC123!!;";

    let future = SqlConnection::connect(core.handle(), connection_string)
        .and_then(|conn| {

            let query = conn.query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id > @P1", &[&0i32])
                .into_stream()
                .take(1);

            query.flatten()
                .map(|row| {
                    let id: i32 = row.get(0);
                    let name: &str = row.get(1);

                    format!("{} - {}", id, name)
                })
                .collect()
        });

    let all_rows = core.run(future).unwrap();
.
    println!("{:?}", all_rows);
}
```

Important points:

1. `conn.query` can be used with *multiple* query statements, so it returns a *stream* of result sets.
2. `conn.query` actually implements a [`StateStream`](https://docs.rs/futures-state-stream/0.1.1/futures_state_stream/trait.StateStream.html), not a `futures::Stream`. For the purposes of the example, I convert it back to a `futures::Stream` with `.into_stream()`. This is non-ideal because we lose the ability to recover the `conn` afterwards.
3. I take only up to the first result set with `.take(1)`.
4. Since we now have a `Stream` of `Stream`s, we use `Stream::flatten` to remove the nesting.
5. Each row is `map`ped to a `String`.
6. The `Stream` is `collect`ed into a single `Future` of a `Vec<String>`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need. Key feature is work with more generic StateStream instead of tiberius::stmt::ResultStreamExt.